# xlrd spreadsheet to python list of dicts

Tags: python, xlrd

I have a spreadsheet and Im using xlrd to parse to python.

[image: spreadsheet]

I need to wrangle it (including the other sheets) into a list of dicts like such:

```
[{"price4-0": 18.22, "price4-1": 21.23, "price4-4": 25.65, "quantity": 100.0, "turnaround": "1days", "size": "2 x 2"},
 {"price4-0": 16.44, "price4-1": 19.43, "price4-4": 23.54, "quantity": 200.0, "turnaround": "1days", "size": "2 x 2"}...]
```

so 'turnaround' dict **value** is taken from the sheetname, and the other dict **keys** are the first row value. I am trying to write it so if another sheet or another row is added it will still work. Basically loop through and add the right values in the right place. I have a hardcoded version which gives correct result but it needs to be dynamic:

```
from pprint import pprint
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('cardprice.xls')

pricelist = []

for i, x in enumerate(wb.sheets()):
    for r in range(x.nrows)[1:]:
        row_values = x.row_values(r)
        pricelist.append({'turnaround':x.name,
                          'size':row_values[0],
                          'quantity':row_values[1],
                          'price4-0':row_values[2],
                          'price4-1':row_values[3],
                          'price4-4':row_values[4]
                          })

pprint(pricelist)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pricelist = []
for i, x in enumerate(wb.sheets()):
    header_cells = x.row(0)
    num_rows = x.nrows - 1
    curr_row = 0
    header = [each.value for each in header_cells]
    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1
        row = [int(each.value) 
               if isinstance(each.value, float)
               else each.value
               for each in work_sheet.row(curr_row)]
        value_dict = dict(zip(header, row))
        value_dict['turnarround'] = x.name

        pricelist.append(value_dict)

print(pricelist)
```

Comment: just had to change: for each in work_sheet.row(curr_row)] to: for each in x.row(curr_row)] -- and didnt need the conversions either. Awesome thanks @roshan